# Session crash after receiving results from Rcpp function

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

The following code compiles and executes correctly, but everytime I run it, my R session gets a fatal error shortly after it finishes. I'm running R version 3.3.2 and Rtools 3.3.

Is there anything I missed? How can I trace what's causing the crash?

```
#include<Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

NumericMatrix dupCheckRcpp(NumericMatrix x) {
    int nrow, ncol;
    int i, j, k, m, n;
    bool flag;
    NumericMatrix dupMat(300,ncol);

    n = 0;
    nrow = 0; ncol = 0;
    nrow = x.nrow();
    ncol = x.ncol();

    for (i = 0; i < nrow - 1 ; ++i) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < nrow; ++j) {
            flag = TRUE;
            for (k = 0; k < ncol; ++k) {
                if (x(i,k) != x(j,k)) {
                    flag = FALSE;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag == TRUE) {
                for (m = 0; m < ncol; ++m) {
                    dupMat(n,m) = x(i,m);
                }
                n = n + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return dupMat;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues that are problematic with your code. We begin by looking at how the result matrix is defined, use of `bool`, and then detail issues with *undefined behavior* (UB) as a result of the matrix subset.

---

The definition of:

```
NumericMatrix dupMat(300, ncol);
```

has two issues:

1. It is placed before `ncol` has been initialized
2. Assumes the `x` matrix has `nrow` fixed at 300.

Move the instantiation of the `dupMat` till after `ncol` and `nrow` are initialized. Alternatively, move it until after you know the amount of duplicate rows.

```
nrow = x.nrow();
ncol = x.ncol();

Rcpp::NumericMatrix dupMat(nrow, ncol);
```

---

In addition, `bool` values within C++ are written in lower case.

That is, use `true` in place of `TRUE` and `false` in place of `FALSE` while setting the values of `flag` variable.

---

There are *three* ways to access individual elements in a `NumericMatrix`, however, we'll only focus on *two* of them that use `i,j` indices.

- `(i,j)`: Accessing elements in this manner forgoes a **bounds check** and subsequent exception flag that warns if the point is not within range. In essence, this access method was causing a UB since `n = n + 1` could easily go *beyond* the row index. Probably the UB caused havoc at a later point when RStudio or R ran a background task causing the crash to happen.
- `.at(i,j)`: This is the *preferred* method as it provides a bounds check and throws a nifty exception e.g.

> Error in dupCheckRcpp(a) : index out of bounds

Which is triggered by the following code snippet:

```
if (flag == true) {
    for (m = 0; m < ncol; ++m) {
        Rcpp::Rcout << "dupMat (" << n << ","<< m << ")" << std::endl <<
            "x (" << i << ","<< m << ")" << std::endl;
        dupMat.at(n, m) = x.at(i, m);
    }
    n = n + 1; // able to exceed nrow.
}
```

The main reason for `n = n + 1` to be hitting the upper bound is due to the placement being within the *second* `for` loop that gets re-instantiated each time.

---

Without knowing your intent behind the duplicate check, outside of guessing that it is checking for duplication that *may* be present within matrix *rows*. I'm going to stop here.

Comment: The goal of the code not shown is to check if a vector is duplicated within a 1000 x 245 matrix. This piece of code distills the full matrix down into only the duplicated rows (~100-200) to speed up that check. The R duplicated() function is the easy way to cut the matrix down into duplicates only, but it is superslow. I suspect that there may be built-in C++ functions that accomplish this faster using vectors, but I needed something quick and dirty that I could implement right away so I used the brute force loops.

Thanks again.

Comment: @SeanS, might I suggest obtaining the rowIDs, creating a matrix containing only the duplicate rows, and then returning as a list?

Comment: Would searching in a list be faster?

Currently I am using the row.names function to speed the comparison between the test vector and the duplicated matrix. That goes pretty fast:  
  
    dupFlag <- length(vectName[vectName %in% dupNames])>0  
  
I started implementing your Rcpp code above, but realized it's inherently inefficient. I send the full matrix to Rcpp to distill it down into just duplicates, then I check the vector against it in R. Why not pass the vector and full matrix to Rcpp and just loop through once to check if it's duplicated, then return the flag?

Comment: In a separate question, I came up with a better approach. Pass a pointer to the matrix and the row number of interest. The overall loop time went from 193.2 secs down to 4.7 secs. Thanks for your help.

http://stackoverflow.com/q/41799654/5701944